# How to make a Batch File edit a text file how a user wants while displaying what is being edited?

Tags: batch-file, word-processor

I am currently creating a word processing software with batch files. I was wondering if anyone knew how to display the text on the screen, so that the user can edit it. I already have a system for creating, viewing, and deleting files, but the editing existing files has me stumped. This is the code for the batch file:

```
@echo off
title Word Processor
:MAIN
cls
echo Type help for help
set /p input=Command-
if %input%==view goto view
if %input%==new goto new
if %input%==exit exit
if %input%==edit goto edit
if %input%==help goto help
if %input%==delete goto delete
:new
cls
set /p words=Type-
set /p name=Name-
echo %words% >> %name%.txt
pause >nul
goto MAIN
:view
cls
set /p file=File to open (without .txt)-
cls
type %file%.txt
pause >nul
goto MAIN
:help
cls
type help.txt
pause >nul
goto MAIN
:edit
cls
echo Not Yet Implemented
pause >nul
exit
:delete
cls
set /p del=File to Delete-
del %del%.txt
echo Deleted...
pause >nul
goto MAIN
```

Comment: Why not open it in Notepad?

Comment: Because I want the whole experience to be within the batch file, you don't open a word document with notepad do you? I want users to be able to do anything the need to the text file of choice.

Comment: You need a text editing program.  In the old DOS days, you used "edlin". In Windows, the most basic text editor is Notepad. I think you need to understand a little more how operating systems work.

Comment: I know that Notepad is the most basic text editor. I use Notepad. I am trying to make my own text editor, because I thought it might be cool. I understand how Operating Systems like Windows work. I want to see exactly how much a batch file can do, even with the help of another scripting language. I am even creating an OS (kinda) out of a batch file and it works great, so the purpose for doing this is to add a text editor for my OS. Thank you and good night.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the help of a VBScript.

The VBScript looks like this

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(0), 1)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strCharacters = objFile.Read(1)
    WshShell.SendKeys strCharacters
Loop
```

Save that as `send.vbs`, and the edit part of your batch file would look like this

```
set /p file=File to edit-
cscript.exe rep.vbs %file%
set /p input=
echo %input% >%file%
```

Basically, you get the file you want to edit and call the VBScript with that file as a parameter. The batch file then falls onto the next line which is another `set /p` which is waiting for input.

Then when the VBScript runs, it reads the file you chose and sends the characters via `SendKeys` which is like simulating keystrokes.

The characters end up being pasted onto the console so you can edit it however you like. When you press enter the edit is saved into the variable and it overwrites the file with the new edit.

Alternatively you could use cmd's built in text editor `edit`, which has a gui of sorts that the user can use to edit and save their files.

Just type `edit` or `edit %file%` to use it.

Hope this helps

Comment: When it edits the file it doesn't show what the original said. This is the same as using my "new" section to save a file with the same name, which would overwrite the previous file. This was helpful, but how can it display the words in the original file, and let you edit it with the interface on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Edit file.txt

This maybe what u want

It's a 16bit program, it's almost exactly like notepad